# Meaning of "to be done in"

Tags: phrases

I was reading a historical article until I have reached to this sentence where it says:

> It is possible that she was done in by the eunuchs on their own initiative, or flung herself down the well.

I am not sure if it means to be tired or meant to be raped?

Comment: I read that as meaning she was killed by the eunuchs (rather than having committed suicide).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to use the `>` quoting character instead of four spaces, which is the typographical convention for software code rather than a quote. I would do it for you, but your quote contains a single `"` and I don't know where the other one goes.

Comment: Please add the link and name the article. It's in the wrong register for an academic work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that she was killed by the eunuchs (rather than having committed suicide).

> **Do in**:
>
> *informal*
>   to murder someone
>
> *I reckon someone did her in to get her money.*
>
> from https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-in

Comment: See https://youtu.be/rR8r5IOvOBk?t=84

Comment: I immediately thought of that scene too.